# update/insert the record - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE- not update the record

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make the statement that inserts or updates the record depending on its presence in the table. If the record in the "drug_name_pl" field is present, it will increase its "vote_sum" value by 1. 
The problem is that the statement creates evey time the a record while trying to update already existing field.

Here is the table structure:

```
               Field            Type       Null Key Default Extra
                id              int(11)    NO   PRI NULL    auto_increment
                drug_name_pl    varchar(11)NO   MUL NULL      
                vote_sum        int(11)    NO       NULL
```

And the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO lek_podstawowe(drug_name_pl) VALUES ('$drug_name_pl') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vote_sum=vote_sum+1";
```

Comment: You need a unique index on `drug_name_pl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add unique key on drug_name_pl

something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX drug_name_pl_unique ON table_name (drug_name_pl)
```

do not forget to change `table_name` to the real name of your table. Please also make sure you escape $drug_name_pl properly to protect application form sql injection

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, I got this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[drug_name_pl_unique] ON lek_podstawowe (drug_name_pl)' at line 1

Comment: see the update, use backtick instead of bracket in mysql `:D`

Comment: @JW. There is no need for backticks or brackets when the names are not reserved keywords.

Comment: @ypercube i agree. It's for safeness. Anyway, I was just trying to tell that they use backtick instead of brackets in mysql. `:D`

Comment: @ypercube After providing your advice to my statement I received this: #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'drug_name_pl_unique'

Comment: fixed! the last problem seems very logic to the alert. Few entries were duplicated so I couldn't create the unique key